# Is there a java equivalent to the q operator in oracle?

Tags: java, string, oracle, operators, string-literals

In Oracle, if you use the [`q` operator](http://ronaldsoracle.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/using-the-q-operator-for-quoting-strings/) it will take the string given literally. For example:

```
select q'[You're awesome]' from dual;
```

Would work fine even though there's a single quote in the middle of the string. This is nice because you don't have to escape all the invalid characters in a string.

**I want to know** (out of curiosity) if there's an equivalent to this in Java. I can't seem to find anything about it on Google. It could be something like this:

```
String literal = q"[I'm a "literal" string]"; //maybe...
```

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: In _what context?_  In regexes?  In `indexOf`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The double-quote syntax is the only syntax for Java string literals.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this.

Generally raw strings would be placed in a properties file.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape your quotes with a backslash.

`String literal = "I'm a \"literal\" string";`

There is no equivalent to the q operator.