# Any other way besides escaping quotes?

Tags: java

I'm making post requests using httpclient, and some of the strings have a lot of quotes, is there anything else I can do besides escaping them. It takes a long time to escape them all.

Comment: What do you mean by "a long time"? Milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, what?

Comment: I inferred that "time" means to type \" instead of just ".

Comment: @davidbuzatto not really, because sometimes I spend about 10 minutes on them. Since I'm editing long http requests. But if there is no other way I'll start using find/replace, I used to check one by one which took me a long time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a java equivalent to the q operator in oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858382/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-the-q-operator-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look into a proper templating system like [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or something like that. Embedded strings just make you look bad, besides being a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can read them from files instead if they're really long, but as far as I know, there's no alternative string literal form in Java.

Answer (score 0):

find/replace? I'm assuming you mean manually, surely programmatically wouldn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

You may use another character, maybe a single quote, and them replace it.

```
String withDQuotes = "a 'string' with 'lots' of 'quotes' here".replace( "'", "\"" );
```

The problem with this solution is if you need to send a single quote. Maybe, you cand use a char that you are certain that will not be send.